# Resource Generators in Sinatra

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sinatra, generator

I have developed few apps in Rails, and I needed to develop an API. I received the advise to build it in Sinatra, so I started looking into it.

It seemed quite nice, but it seems that a lot of things you get automated in Rails does not seem to exist in Sinatra. Specifically, I seem to have to write my resources from scratch. eg. The model itself, the migrations, and the REST routes.

I was wondering if there are any generators for Sinatra like the ones provided by Rails? Or should I simply use Rails if I want these kind of things automated?

Comment: Sinatra is bare bones, no generators so far. But you can use a gem that lets you use most rails plugins in any ruby app. Don't know what it's called so it's just a comment.

Comment: found it: http://nicksda.apotomo.de/2012/06/using-rails-gems-like-simple_form-in-sinatra-or-anywhere/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [`sinatra-rest` gem](http://blindgaenger.github.com/sinatra-rest/) that can be used to handle RESTful routes. Quoted below for convenience:

---

[sinatra-rest is] a set of templates to introduce RESTful routes into Sinatra. The only thing for you to do is to provide the views. Automatically works nicely for models based on ActiveRecord, DataMapper, or Stone.

For example, if your model’s class is called Person you only need to add this line:

```
rest Person
```

Which will add the following RESTful routes to your application. (Note the pluralization of `Person` to the `/people/*` routes.)

```
Verb    Route            Controller   View
GET     /people          index        /people/index.haml
GET     /people/new      new          /people/new.haml
POST    /people          create       → redirect to show
GET     /people/1        show         /people/show.haml
GET     /people/1/edit   edit         /people/edit.haml
PUT     /people/1        update       → redirect to show
DELETE  /people/1        destroy      → redirect to index
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't personally use Sinatra but a lot of feedback I've gotten from other Rails developers is that they eventually end up switching back to Rails. I'm sure there are good arguments for using Sinatra over Rails, but if you already know Rails, and you don't have speed or application size constraints, I would just stick with that.

Another alternative to Sinatra is the [Rails API](https://github.com/rails-api/rails-api) project which doesn't include any of the view-related part of the Rails framework. I have used that in the past and liked it, but was it better than just using Rails? It's hard to say.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! :) do you know why they end up switching back to Rails?

Comment: Mostly because they kept adding more and more libraries and features that were already built into Rails.

Answer (score 1):

You should check out [Padrino](http://www.padrinorb.com/) if you must have Sinatra.

> Padrino is a ruby framework built upon the Sinatra web library.
>   Sinatra is a DSL for creating simple web applications in Ruby. Padrino
>   was created to make it fun and easy to code more advanced web
>   applications while still adhering to the spirit that makes Sinatra
>   great!

Or as Beerlington mentioned, you could use [Rails API](https://github.com/rails-api/rails-api) if you feel more at home with Rails.  We've been using it recently with good success.  We created a Simple API, with a mongo backend.  Starts up very quickly :)

Comment: Awesome. I will have a look at Padrino in more detail. I am aiming to build the front-end in Knockout.js, such that if I switch the server end to use Node.js - it will simply work. Would it be possible to re-arrange the structure of Padrino so that I have a "server" folder, and "client" folder, and make it obvious that the server and client side are completely decoupled? I find this distinction hard to see in a Rails project. Thanks!

Comment: @Karan why not build them as two separate Rack apps? Then they can live in different folders but be run in the same Rack using `use` and `run`.

Answer (score 0):

> Or should I simply use Rails if I want these kind of things automated?

If you're that used to Rails that using Ruby is a problem, then maybe. Alternatively, you could try this API generator that uses Sinatra:

https://github.com/mattetti/Weasel-Diesel